# How to convert Firestore Timestamp to Date() - Firestore V9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Before updating to V9, I use this:

```js
let data = doc.data();

for (let field in data) {
    let value = data[field];

    // If value is an instance of Timestamp, convert it to javascript Date()
    if (value instanceof firebase.firestore.Timestamp) {
        data[field] = value.toDate();
    }
}
```

But now, after updating to V9, I run into 2 problems, and the documentation mentions nothing about Timestamp for javascript SDK:

1. `firebase.firestore.Timestamp` is no longer available to use to check if a field is a Timestamp Object.
2. None of the field has the "toDate()" function any more.

So my questions are, with the javascript V9 SDK:

1. How do I check if a field is an instance of Timestamp?
2. How do I convert an instance of Timestamp into Date() object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I check if a field is an instance of Timestamp?

You can import `Timestamp` class from Firestore package.

> How do I convert an instance of Timestamp into Date() object?

This method exists on a Timestamp object.

```
import { Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore"

const timeObj = new Timestamp();

console.log(timeObj instanceof Timestamp)
console.log(timeObj.toDate());
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem but I wanted to expand a bit on Dharmaraj's answer.

```
import { Timestamp } from "firebase/firestore";

/* RETRIEVED_TIMESTAMP = value that you saved in Firestore using serverTimestamp(). 
 This gets returned as a FieldValue and needs to be cast as a Timestamp */

const fieldVal = (RETRIEVED_TIMESTAMP as Timestamp);

/* new Timestamp takes the seconds and nanoseconds as input parameters */
const timeStamp = new Timestamp(fieldVal.seconds, 
fieldVal.nanoseconds);

const date = timeStamp.toDate()
console.log(date);`
```